# Enabled SSL gives issues

Tags: ssl, wordpress, shopp

I really dont know what is the problem nor does my website hosting providers. Im using wordpress to run my business and Im using a shop plugin called "Shopp". Whenever I fill in the Paypal Pro details to process credit card on my website, I get teh following on the checkout page: "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

I can assure you that the plugin has nothing to do with it as I have tried different shop plugins. Can someone help? The url is www.imayne.co.uk/shop/checkout

Few info:
I have SSL automatically installed by my provider
Hosted package was said to be Linux

Answer (score 0):

Usually that's caused by a page (or pages) that simply redirect to each other:

first.php:

```
<?php
header("Location: second.php")
```

second.php

```
<?php
header("Location: first.php");
```

or a single page that redirects to itself. check your server logs to see exactly what the requested URL is, and then look for a wordpress rule that'd cause the redirect. Possibly you're trying to redirect from non-SSL to SSL-enabled pages, but are doing the redirect wrong, so you end up back at the same page, which then tries to redirect to SSL, fails, etc...

---

and indeed, after trying your link, you get redirected to `https://www.imayne.co.uk/shop/checkout/`, which then keeps on redirecting to itself. So, your shopping car system would appear to be broken.

Comment: Thanks! I have checked the log file but it confused my eyes. Also if you could take your time with me as I have no idea what is first and secont.php. What to look for it the log?

Comment: I'd check what's happening on your initial url and the checkout page. They're looking for something that isn't there, and forcing a redirect, which simply does the same check again and goes into an infinite loop. Logs won't help too much for that.

Comment: Hi but how to stop it? As I fill in details for the Paypal pro the issue comes in on that page.

Comment: No idea. I tried to delve into WP's guts once... ONCE. I'm still in therapy from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your site has been removed so I don't know if you were able to solve the issue.

One thing to keep in mind when using Shopp is, you need a dedicated SSL certificate. A "shared hosting" certificate won't work.